# Which phrase is more natural to and a conversation, "that's it" or "that's about it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

When ending a conversation or discussion what is the best phrase?

"That's it" or "that's about it"?

Do they both mean the same thing?

Comment: In any given context where the intended meaning is ***I / We are finished, The job is done, That is all,...*** they're both equivalent  (neither has "a shade of difference" compared to the other). But If you'd just explained something to someone, and they summarised what they'd just learned to confirm they really ***have*** understood you, *That's it!* would imply *You have understood **perfectly***, whereas *That's about it!* would imply *You have a **reasonable, but not perfect** understanding of the situation.*

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what *kind* of conversation it is!

"That's it" sounds a bit abrupt, as though you were telling the other person that you have had enough of their company. If the purpose of the conversation was to discuss a particular topic, you might say something like "Well, I think that's about it, don't you?" when you finish the discussion - but if you are having a chat with a friend, it would be better to say something like "I really must go now, as I have to get on with my work/get a meal ready/go into town." But this is about interpersonal skills as much as English!

Comment: We might as well compare and contrast ***That's all**!* with ***That's all there is to it**!* For most purposes, it's probably enough to just say the extra verbiage *(**about, there is to it**)* is just a "meaningless" little "verbal flourish".

Answer (score 1):

When someone has been struggling to say something or remember something or identify something in reality, and finally says it, the person will say: "That's it." Or the person's interlocutor will say it.

WHEREAS:

"That's about it." is used to say that an explanation or discussion is finished or over. It is not used to identify something as a deixis (like "pointing at something").

So, the phrases are used in completely different contexts.

Comment: "That's it" also means "I'm finished [with something]" - someone trying to work in a noisy house might exclaim "That's it, I'm leaving!".

Comment: Yes, that's true. But that is a different meaning to the confusion brought to bear here...